# How can I change the color of the prompt character in zsh with powerlevel10k?

Tags: linux, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to change the color of the prompt character in my terminal. I looked at .p10k.zsh but I could not find this option. I am using pure theme of powerlevel10k.

[image: 1]

I want to change the color of `$` (prompt_char) in the screenshot but not the monospace text color.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can put into your `PS1` (respectively `prompt`) variable a `%F{yellow}` right in front of the `$` to turn on the colour and a `%f` to turn it off.

Example:

```
PS1='%~ %F{yellow}$%f'
```

See the section titled *SIMPLE PROMPT ESCAPES* in *man zshmisc*.